# SMO "Restore failed for Server" Restoring Backup From File

Tags: c#, sql, restore, smo, database-restore

I'm using the following code to restore a backup sql database with C# and SMO.

```
void RestoreDatabaseWithSMO(string sConnect, string dbName, string backUpPath)
{
    using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(sConnect))
    {
        cnn.Open();
        cnn.ChangeDatabase("master");

        ServerConnection sc = new ServerConnection(cnn);
        Server sv = new Server(sc);

        if (!sv.Databases.Contains(dbName))
            throw new Exception("this DataBase does not exist");

        // Create backup device item for the backup
        BackupDeviceItem bdi = new BackupDeviceItem(backUpPath, DeviceType.File);

        // Create the restore object
        Restore resDB = new Restore();
        resDB.PercentComplete += new PercentCompleteEventHandler(percentComplete);
        resDB.PercentCompleteNotification = 10;
        resDB.Devices.Add(bdi);
        resDB.NoRecovery = false;
        resDB.ReplaceDatabase = true;
        resDB.Database = dbName;
        resDB.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;

        // Restore the database
        resDB.SqlRestore(sv);//Exception
    }
}
```

but in the last line I got below exception !!!

```
{"Restore failed for Server '\\\\.\\pipe\\3F103E6E-3FD4-47\\tsql\\query'. "}
```

What's wrong with it ?
Could you please guide me? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done it with T-SQL

[Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046708/exclusive-access-could-not-be-obtained-because-the-database-is-in-use/4048643#4048643)

```
void Restore(string ConnectionString, string DatabaseFullPath, string backUpPath)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        con.Open();

        string UseMaster = "USE master";
        SqlCommand UseMasterCommand = new SqlCommand(UseMaster, con);
        UseMasterCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        string Alter1 = @"ALTER DATABASE [" + DatabaseFullPath + "] SET Single_User WITH Rollback Immediate";
        SqlCommand Alter1Cmd = new SqlCommand(Alter1, con);
        Alter1Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        string Restore = @"RESTORE DATABASE [" + DatabaseFullPath + "] FROM DISK = N'" + backUpPath + @"' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10";
        SqlCommand RestoreCmd = new SqlCommand(Restore, con);
        RestoreCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        string Alter2 = @"ALTER DATABASE [" + DatabaseFullPath + "] SET Multi_User";
        SqlCommand Alter2Cmd = new SqlCommand(Alter2, con);
        Alter2Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        labelReport.Text = "Successful";
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is because it's a T-SQL answer to an SMO question.