# Database restore error in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046708/exclusive-access-could-not-be-obtained-because-the-database-is-in-use)

I use C#, .net4 and SQL Server 2008 R2 in project and use this code to restore a database:

```
_comm = new SqlCommand("use master; RESTORE DATABASE [DB1] FROM  DISK = @Address WITH  RESTRICTED_USER,  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 10; use DB1;", _conn);
        _comm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        _comm.Parameters.AddRange(new SqlParameter[] 
                {
                new SqlParameter("@Address", _path)
                });

            _conn.Open();
            _comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The following error is displayed:

> Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use.
>    RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
>    Changed database context to 'master'.
>    Changed database context to 'DB1'.

Comment: The message is pretty clear: the `DB1` database is still being used by someone else - either you have query windows in SQL Server Management Studio open, or some other application is still connected to that database. You **cannot** restore a database while it's being used.

Comment: Also: you should not use `use master` in your SQL statement inside C# - if you want to execute something on the `master` database - you need to have an appropriate connection string:  `server=YourServer;database=master; ......`

Comment: i delete 'use master;' But there are still Error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its better to use SMO (cause no need for master) once you are connected to the server you do whatever you want

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

...

        Server myServer = new Server(@".\SQLExpress");

        Database mydb = myServer.Databases["DB1"];
        if(mydb!=null)
           myServer.KillAllProcesses(mydb.Name);//detach

        Restore restoreDB = new Restore();
        restoreDB.Database = mydb.Name;

        restoreDB.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
        restoreDB.Devices.AddDevice(_path, DeviceType.File);


        restoreDB.ReplaceDatabase = true;

        restoreDB.NoRecovery = false;

        restoreDB.SqlRestore(myServer);
```

**BACKUP**

```
        Server myServer = new Server(@".\SQLExpress");

        Database mydb = myServer.Databases["DB1"];

        Backup bkp = new Backup();

        bkp.Action = BackupActionType.Database;

        bkp.Database = mydb.Name;

        bkp.Devices.AddDevice(_path, DeviceType.File);

        bkp.BackupSetName = "DB1 backup";//optional
        bkp.BackupSetDescription = "mybackup dated " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");//optional

        bkp.Initialize = true;
        bkp.Incremental = false;

        bkp.SqlBackup(myServer);
```

**References :**

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll**

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll**

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll**

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll**

Comment: I can not use Server & Database & Restore Class. please give me reference for class

Comment: beleive me, using SMO will help you a lot (its like using SqlServer Management Studio but in C#), you can Backup , restore, Transfert DB from a server to another, fetch all information in a strongly typed classes

Comment: please give me SMO code for backup. thx :-)

Comment: @S3ddi9 can you give me the complete code where i can put the database name, path, or can you comment your code please thanks

Comment: @S3ddi9 can you give me the complete code where i can put the database name, path, or can you comment your code. or if you could put both restore and backup in  two different functions with parameters. please thanks

Answer (score 0):

Insert the line below before calling the `SqlCommand`:

```
_conn.ChangeDatabase("master");
```